# NetBeans IDE 11.2: Incorrect credentials for repository at git@gitlab

Tags: git, netbeans, gitlab

I'm having this problem since I have my new Mac with Catalina and installed NetBeans IDE 11.2.  To make a 'git push' I have to go to linux console and manually execute the command "git push" which is always successful (so that means my public key has been correctly installed on the server).
I had no problem on my old Mac (previous MacOS too) and Netbeans 8.2.

Any idea ?
Bernard